# .htaccess redirect for specific URL structures

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following URL:

```
https://www.site-a.xyz/tutorials/post-name/2
```

I need it to redirect to the following URL

```
https://www.site-b.xyz/post-name/2
```

Essentially If there is a trailing number element to the URL (in this case `/2`) I need the `/tutorials/` part of the URL to be removed.

***Note: ONLY if there is a trailing number***

Comment: Is `site-a` and `site-b` hosted on the same filesystem? Or completely separate?

Comment: Completely separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (using mod_rewrite) near the top of your .htaccess file at `www.site-a.xyz`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tutorials/([^/]+/\d+)$ https://www.site-b.xyz/$1 [R=302,L]
```

In this case, the trailing "number" can be 1 or more digits. If it is only a single digit (as in your example) then this should be simplified (change `\d+` to `\d`). The `$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Note that this is a `302` (temporary) redirect, if this is intended to be permanent then change to `301` when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic.

**UPDATE:** To allow for an *optional* trailing slash on the source URL then add `/?` near the end of the `RewriteRule` pattern, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^tutorials/([^/]+/\d+)/?$ https://www.site-b.xyz/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This notatably strips that optional trailing slash from the redirect target. (Thus avoiding any duplicate content issues.)

Comment: You answer works well - but what if I have a URL with a trailing slash? i.e - https://www.site-a.xyz/tutorials/post-name/2/

Comment: For some reason I cant add a trailing slash to the above URL - but I hope you get what I mean!

Comment: The above directive did not allow for a trailing slash (just a "trailing number", as stated in your question). I've updated my answer to allow for an _optional_ trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm I have tested the solution and it works perfectly.